# Find a basis for the image of the given linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the image of the following linear transformation
$$ t:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$ and $$ t(x,y,z)=(x+3y-2z,x-y+z,3x+y)$$

I have found the following basis:

$$ \left\{ (1,1,3),(3,-1,1),(-2,1,0) \right\}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Well, what do you think? One way to check your work is to compute the rank of the transformation and see if you have the right number of vectors in the basis.

Comment: The transformation has rank 2 so one vector must be the linear combination of the other two. How do I find it?

Comment: So, the image of the transformation is two-dimensional, but you’ve got three vectors in your basis. That’s definitely not right.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks a lot amd.